# how to build a pagination for the API api.rawg.io

Tags: angular, api, pagination

I am triying to build a pagination for this API https://api.rawg.io/docs/#tag/games

In this page they explain the parameters that the API  returns
https://rawgthedocs.orels.sh/api/#basics
[image]

my http request `return this.http.get('https://api.rawg.io/api/games?dates=2010-01-01,2020-12-31&page_size=20&page=3');`

in my angular component I get the data

```
constructor(
    private gamesService:GamesService,
    private router: Router,
  ) {
    this.gamesService.getListGames().subscribe( (data: any) =>{
      console.log(data.results);
      this.gameslist = data.results;
      this.count = data.results.length;
      console.log(this.count);

      if(data.results.page == 3)
      {
        
      }    

     });
```

I dont know how to get the page parameter that in the request it is &page=3 and the next and prev parameters to build the pagination

Answer (score 0):

Here, first you have to collect the `data.next` and `data.previous` urls and then for next or previous pagination use those links.

And to use the `dates` parameter, create a object of `HttpParams` -

```
let params = new HttpParams();
params = params.append('dates','2010-01-01,2020-12-31');
```

finally add them to your `gamesService.getListGames()` http function

```
this.http.get(url, {params: this.params});
```

where `params` is the above created `HttpParams` object.